# How to create document from data array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have FlexTable with chekBoxes in first cell of each row, when checkBox is true data from FlexTable's row is collected in variable. Now I need to create document with table that contains table with data from variable. I tried to store string's value in Hidden but it doesn't work and can't figure out how to realise it.
All my (although the code is not really my, code is almost half @Sergeinsas's) code is avaliable here: http://pastebin.com/aYmyA7N2, thankyou in advance.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning :-)   -  could you tell what is the final purpose of this.?  Do you want to send an email or store a document ?

Comment: Right now I want just store the document, but in future I want to create html from it

Comment: I suggested a code to create the doc but it would also be possible to build the HTML directly from the array of data... if you don't intend to use a lot of complex formatting it would probably be more efficient to build the html from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your code... widgets like `hidden` can only have string values and they can only return string values when you retrieve their values.

One possible and easy way to convert arrays to string (and back) is to use a combination of `join()` and `split()` , here is the modified code (relevant part only) that works.

```
// Storing checked rows
function check(e) {
  var checkedArray = [];
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).getValues();
  for(var n=0; n < data.length;++n){
    if(e.parameter['check'+n]=='true'){
      checkedArray.push(data[n].join(','));// convert data row array to string with comma separator
    }
  }

  var hidden = app.getElementById('hidden');

  hidden.setValue(checkedArray.join('|'));// convert array to string with | separator

  return app;
}

function click(e) {
  var hiddenVal = e.parameter.hidden.split('|');// e.parameter.hidden is a string, split back in an array of strings, each string should be splitted too to get the original array of arrays

  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  var table = []
  for(var n in hiddenVal){
    table.push(hiddenVal[n].split(','));// reconstruction of a 2D array
  }
  DocumentApp.create('doc '+time).getBody().appendTable(table);// the table is in the document
}
```

Full code [available here](http://pastebin.com/ZyKbr5uc)

---

EDIT : suggestion : if you put your headers in your spreadsheet you could retrieve them in your final table quite easily like this :

```
function check(e) {
  var checkedArray = [];
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lastrow,lastcol).getValues();
  checkedArray.push(data[0].join(','));// if you have headers in your spreadsheet, you could add headers by default
  for(var n=0; n < data.length;++n){
    if(e.parameter['check'+n]=='true'){
      checkedArray.push(data[n].join(','));
    }
  }
```

You could also use `data[0]` in the `doGet` function to build the header of your `UI`, I think this would make your code more easy to maintain without hardcoding of data.... but this is only a suggestion ;-)